# Elasticsearch get nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying the following query:

```
{
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "payload",
        "payload_parsed"
    ],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "id": "some-id-123"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`payload` is a JSON string, and `payload_parsed` is the parsed payload. I do not know what the payload is in advance and how many level of nesting it has. I'm not doing a query on `payload_parsed`, but rather on `id` and this is the error I get: `"field [payload_parsed] isn't a leaf field"`

How do I fetch the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documented feature. In `fields` you can use only leaf nodes, i.e. nodes that do not have children. 
In your case you need to get that field via `_source`.
Try the following query:

```
{
    "fields": [
        "id",
        "payload"
    ],
    "_source": "payload_parsed",
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "id": "some-id-123"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```